# Android: CountDownTimer does this class affected by the date/time setting

Tags: android, date, alarmmanager, countdowntimer

When using AlarmManager, if I modify the date/time setting on android, the alarm manager will be affected.Let's say,I set the alarm for tomorrow, if I change the date to tomorrow the AlarmManager will fire.

Does this CountDownTimer act the same?

Comment: As I know Android sends a notification on each tick to listeners. These listeners check time with a some value and can make smth when the time will be valid. So, I think if you set the alarm and change date then `AlarmManager` will fire on new time. E.g. alarm 6:00. You changed the system time from 5:00 to 5:59 then it will fire in a minute.

Comment: "Does this CountDownTimer act the same?" - No.